# a strange problem: wordpress theme doesn't show up

Tags: wordpress, themes

wp 3.1

**before:**

I click themes, twentyten theme is one of Available Themes

**after:**

I rename default theme folder twentyten to yoyo, and change some value in style.css, then click themes link, yoyo doesn't show up.

if I rename yoyo back to twentyten, then twentyten show up again.

PS: I check permission with yoyo, it is readable to everyone.

Comment: problem solved!!! i'm using multisite, and theme must be enabled in network first!!!